# Unix command to select the best edge values from a network file

Tags: python, awk

I have a tab-delimited data representing network data (undirected). Among the duplicated edges, I wanted to select those edges for which I have the higher absolute value of the log values. 
I have written a code in python, but its taking a lot of time. I would be grateful if someone helps me with an awk command. Kindly note, the network is undirected, i.e. A--B and B--A are duplicate edges.

Test data

```
Gene1   Gene2   Log
AT1G01020   AT1G01010   1.682708
AT1G01020   AT1G01010   -1.90043
AT1G01020   AT1G01010   -1.832192
AT1G01070   AT1G01060   -0.591932
AT1G01070   AT1G01060   -1.204241
AT1G01073   AT1G01070   0.790549
AT1G01060   AT1G01070   1.214972

Expected Output

AT1G01020   AT1G01010   -1.90043
AT1G01070   AT1G01060   1.214972
AT1G01073   AT1G01070   0.790549
```

```
gene_table=file1.readlines() # In the real file, j[12]=Gene1, j[13]=Gene2 and j[27]=log value
lfc=[]
for j in gene_table:
    j=j.split("\t")
    j[12]=j[12].strip()
    j[13]=j[13].strip()
    lfc=[]
    int_list=[]
    lfc.append(float(j[27]))
    int_list.append(j[0])
    dict_int={}
    for k in gene_table:
        k=k.split("\t")
        k[12]=k[12].strip()
        k[13]=k[13].strip()
        if (j[0]!=k[0]) and ((j[12]==k[12] and j[13]==k[13]) or (j[12]==k[13] and j[12]==k[13])):
            lfc.append(float(k[27]))
    dict_int=dict(zip(int_list, lfc))
    x=max(lfc, key=abs)
    #print x
    listOfKeys = [key  for (key, value) in dict_int.items() if value == x]
    print listOfKeys
```

Comment: First, you process your data MANY times. Why do you do splitting and striping in the _inner_ `for` loop? Process your edge table once and use it as many times as you want. Second, what is `j[12]` and `j[13]`? You do not have tha many columns if your file. Please construct a realistic example.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very inefficient. Consider using Pandas, as it has all the tools necessary for the problem. Start by reading the data (I assume your table has only three columns, but if it has more, adjust the column numbers accordingly):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("file.txt", sep="\s+", header=None)
```

Add three more columns with node names to resolve the ambiguity of bidirectionaily and negative logs:

```
df['start'] = df[[0,1]].max(axis=1)
df['end'] = df[[0,1]].min(axis=1)
df['abslog'] = df[2].abs()
```

Find the largest abs logs:

```
df.sort_values('abslog').groupby(['start','end'])\
                        .last()[[2]]
#                            2
#start     end                
#AT1G01020 AT1G01010 -1.900430
#AT1G01070 AT1G01060  1.214972
#AT1G01073 AT1G01070  0.790549
```

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR>1 {
    key = ($1 > $2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1)
    max[key] = ( abs(max[key]) > abs($3) ? max[key] : $3 )
}
END {
    for (key in max) {
        print key, max[key]
    }
}

function abs(val) { return (val < 0 ? - val : val) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
AT1G01070       AT1G01060       1.214972
AT1G01020       AT1G01010       -1.90043
AT1G01073       AT1G01070       0.790549
```

Comment: Hi Ed, this is very close to what I need. Could you kindly modify the script to select the absolute value of $3 ? Then it will exactly match the expected output. Thanks

Comment: OK, I updated my answer based on what I now think you must mean by that given there are negative values in your posted expected output. If I misunderstood your requirements then please update your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

A short one-liner using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) and a bit of `awk` preprocessing to turn `A B X` into `B A X` (to get your expected results which have the larger node of each edge first):

```
$ awk '$1 < $2 {tmp=$2; $2=$1; $1=tmp} 1' input.txt | datamash -Ws -g 1,2 absmax 3
AT1G01020   AT1G01010   -1.90043
AT1G01070   AT1G01060   1.214972
AT1G01073   AT1G01070   0.790549
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is awk-like in approach and efficiency, using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).  It produces TSV output but you could easily modify the program if you prefer some other delimiter or some other format.

```
# Note: for numbers, jq's length == abs
def MAXAV_BY(stream; k; v):
  reduce stream as $x ({};
    ($x|k) as $key | ($x|v) as $value 
    | if has($key) 
      then if ($value|length) > (.[$key]|length)
           then .[$key] = $value 
           else .
           end
      else .[$key] = $value
      end) ;         

def parse:
  [splits(" +")]
  | (if .[0] < .[1] then .[1] + "\t" + .[0] else .[0] + "\t" + .[1] end) as $k
  | [$k, (.[2] | tonumber)];


MAXAV_BY(inputs | parse; .[0]; .[1])
| keys_unsorted[] as $k
| [($k | splits("\t")), .[$k]]
| @tsv
```

### Invocation

Assuming the above jq program is in a file named maxav.jq:

```
jq -nr -R -f maxav.jq test.txt
```

### Output

```
AT1G01020   AT1G01010   -1.90043
AT1G01070   AT1G01060   1.214972
AT1G01073   AT1G01070   0.790549
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, my python code would have looked like this:

```
d = dict()
with open(filename) as f:
    next(f) # get rid of header line
    for line in f:
        col = line.split()
        key = ' '.join(sorted(col[:2]))
        val = float(col[2])
        d[key] = val if abs(val) - abs(d.get(key, 0)) > 0 else d.get(key, 0)
```

Result:

```
# for k, v in d.items():
#     print(k, v)
# AT1G01010 AT1G01020 -1.90043
# AT1G01060 AT1G01070 1.214972
# AT1G01070 AT1G01073 0.790549
```